# Android two TextInputEditText and two way addTextChangedListener

Tags: android, android-edittext, addtextchangedlistener

I have two  TextInputEditText fields:

```
TextInputEditText fromData = (TextInputEditText) view.findViewById(R.id.fromData);
TextInputEditText toData = (TextInputEditText) view.findViewById(R.id.toData );
```

Both fields has `addTextChangedListener()` and should change text of each other. But that cause an error (recursion). Because when I write some text in fromData, toData text also changes, and if toData text changes fromData also should changes.

How can I make textchangelistener to work in two way ?

Answer (score 0):

Override the listener and if the text it is being changed to is the same as it already is don't change it.

So text is changed in `fromData` and it calls the on text changed listener in on text changed check if the text being changed is equal to the text that already exists in the textview if it is don't do anything.

```
onTextChanged(String newText) {
     if (!newText.equals(fromData.getText())) {
           fromData.setText(newText);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a global variable like **focusedTextView** and then **add on touch listeners** to both textviews. Now when a particular view is touched.

You just set the value of this variable to that view.

**Finally**, in your addTextChangeListener **just check** what is the **current value of this global variable** and just change the text of other textView which is not focused.

Hopefully this will give you the two way result that you want.

Let me know if it changes anything for you.